# Excel VBA: convert R1C1 notation to A1 notation

Tags: excel

**issue**

- I'm a "data tester" and I test websites by writing SQL queries then using Excel to process the data and validate data during test execution
- Sometimes we want to use R1C1 nontation in our VBA (e.g. 478,9) but usually we prefer A1 notation (e.g. I478)
- Also, range objects return numbers (e.g. ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count would return 9 not "I") but business people refer to "column I" never to "column 9"
- The point is we need a way to convert R1C1 notation to A1 notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**solution**

- use the Excel **Address** function
  [image]